# InnoSetup - how to make setup.exe into 875kB? So that users download it faster and on download it will download another one?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, inno-setup

Using `InnoSetup` i prepared my `maininstaller.exe` which is very large such as `90Mb` when user downloads it, it take sometimes ages.

as a result often user ignores it and my setup is incomplete because of not user friendly.

Now i have compared `Google Chrome/Canary web browsers` concepts, they are also large in size, but they used 2 types of installer one is very tiny small size installer, which is just to download quickly and execute, to download the second large main installer, this method is more friendly to deploy large installation, and mostly accepted by many users.

Now, How can i do such (like `Google Chrome web browser` installer) with `Innosetup`? one `first_setup.exe` which is very tiny in size, so that user can quickly download it, but once that is executed it will go to internet and download my `maininstaller.exe` and make sure its downloaded correctly then execute it.

Is this possible? any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can build some sort of online installer which will e.g. download only components that the user chose during the setup wizard. For downloading component files or component setup files you can use e.g. the [`IDP plugin`](https://code.google.com/p/inno-download-plugin/) which I would prefer, or [`InnoTools Downloader`](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50).

Martijn Laan even considered to build in downloading feature for installed files in [`this issue`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/issues/23).