# Download a file while installing by inno setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

```
[Files]
Source: D:\VBproject\YY\inst\YY.exe; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: D:\VBproject\YY\inst\YY.dll; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
```

That is my file list above, and I want to install the YY.dll from the internet for example 
http://www.example.com/yy.dll , not pack it to setup.exe

Is there any way can do that? Thanks alot

Comment: There's a link to a sample script that shows how to do this on the [Inno Setup Third-Party](http://www.jrsoftware.org/is3rdparty.php) page. (See the link for Inno Tools Downloader on that page.) You have to first download the file to the local computer, and then launch the file from there.

Comment: Got it. I will check it out

Comment: possible duplicate of [InnoSetup - how to make setup.exe into 875kB? So that users download it faster and on download it will download another one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031927/innosetup-how-to-make-setup-exe-into-875kb-so-that-users-download-it-faster-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the [ISTool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/istool/) plugin:

```
#include 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ISTool\isxdl.iss'

[Code]
const
  dotnetRedistURL = 'http://www.example.com/yy.dll ';

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    isxdl_AddFile(dotnetRedistURL, ExpandConstant('{app}\data\yy.dll'));
    isxdl_SetOption('Updating', 'Updating to the latest DLL...');
    isxdl_SetOption('Please wait...', 'Updating...');
    isxdl_DownloadFiles(WizardForm.Handle);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If you'd decide one day to modify the main panel, or that small icon on the top right side, you'll find out that [`isxdl plugin breaks their look`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25085247/960757).